# MySQL. Deleting from the parent table and not deleting the data from the child table

Tags: mysql

I want to be able to delete rows from the parent table (the are in a relationship) without have to automatically delete the data from the child table. Will that be possible?

for example:
ill be deleting id no. 1 from the parent table:

```
id | name
1  | robert *this one will be deleted.
2  | landon
```

and the child table will not be affected:

```
stu|id|book
1    1  bible
1    2  english
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

just don't put referential integrity constraints on the table if you want to be able to have orphans like this. You might want to consider "soft deletion"

Comment: its possible not to have integrity constraints? im using mySQL workbench.

Comment: Sure, I use Heidi sql typically when using MySQL, just create the table and don't create constraints. I think in workbench if you draw the lines on the ERD, you will get constaints

Comment: but if i delete those lines, it would also mean that i will drop the foreign keys.. am I right?

Comment: i believe so.. don't have MySQL in front of me right now

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `"DELETE cascade"` part from your DDL of `table1`. You should set it `"DELETE NO ACTION"`

Comment: yes, i changed it from CASCADE to NO ACTION .. but its does not do anything.

Comment: when I did that i had this exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Comment: If the system is not live, then you can try drop the table and recreate it. No other solution in mind! Thanks